# Javascrip Reverse int.toString(32), base32?

Tags: javascript, base32

I use this to encode number to string

```js
let n = 4358799123
console.log(n.toString(32)) // 41srvoj
```

how to reverse `41srvoj` to `4358799123`?

Comment: `parseInt(n.toString(32), 32)`